Hodge numbers of a complement
Let $Y\subset X$ be an analytic subvariety of codimension $d$ of a smooth compact complex variety $X$. Denote $U = X\setminus Y$. The relative cohomology exact sequence implies that
$$
H^i(X) \to H^i(U)
$$
is an isomorphism for $i\le 2d-2$. Is a similar result true for Hodge cohomology? Namely, is the map
$$
H^i(X,\Omega^j_X) \to H^i(U,\Omega^j_U)
$$
an isomorphism for $i+j \le 2d-2$ (or for some other reasonable constraint on $i$ and $j$)
EDIT: The result is obviously false when $d=1$ as pointed out in the comments. However, when $d\ge 2$,
$$
H^{n,0}(X) \to H^{n,0}(U)
$$
is an iso for all $n$ because $\Omega^n_X$ is locally free. So I still hope that this statement can be true, possibly with another constraint on $i$ and $j$.

No, it fails already when $X$ is a compact Riemann surface, $Y$ is a point, and $i=j=0$. The right side is infinite dimensional, but the left isn't.
